# Bootstrap : More Elegant way to move a div on scroll

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to make a div stay on top right as I scroll the browser down. It looks good when it's viewed in desktop. But it's a mess when viewed on tablet etc. Is there a more elegant way to position the div in such a way that the user sees while scrolling down in all screens. 
I'm using Bootstrap. Here is [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/897fb0mj/)
 Here is the HTML bootstrap code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="ShopCartApp">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Starter Template for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
   <style type="text/css">
    body {
  padding-top: 50px;
}
.starter-template {
  padding: 40px 15px;
  text-align: center;
}
#divTotal{
  background-color: green;

}
   </style>


  </head>

  <body>



    <div class="container">

      <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading">
                    <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
                </div>
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
                    </div>
                     <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio">Option 1</label>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio1">Option 1</label>
                    </div>
                     <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio1">Option 1</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio1">Option 1</label>
                    </div>  
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio2">Option 1</label>
                    </div>
                     <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio2">Option 1</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio2">Option 1</label>
                    </div>
              </div>
            </div>

            <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio3">Option 1</label>
                    </div>
                     <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio3">Option 1</label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="radio">
                        <label><input type="radio" name="optradio3">Option 1</label>
                    </div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div style="position:fixed;top:20px;float:right;right:0px;" class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
              <div id="divTotal" class="panel-heading">
                  <h3 class="panel-title">Total</h3>
              </div>
              <div class="panel-body">
                  <h2>Total</h2>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div><!-- /.row  -->


    </div><!-- /.container -->


   <script type="text/javascript" src="angular.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You can add classes for small devices `class="col-md-8 col-sm-8 col-xs-8"` and `class="col-md-4 col-sm-4 sol-xs-4"`

Comment: would be helpful , if you could provide a demo

Comment: Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/897fb0mj/1/)

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">

  <div class="row">
    <div style="position:fixed;top:20px;float:left;left:0px;"class="col-sm-8">
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know there is no CSS solution to achieve a `position: fixed` container for older mobile browsers. You could write a javascript that adjusts the position of the container on each scroll event, but that would not work so nicely on iOS, because iOS fires the onscroll event only after scrolling has finished, and not while scrolling. This would mean that the container jumps to it's fixed position after scrolling instead of staying there.

However there are some advanced JS libraries out there that emulate the scroll behaviour using a fake scroll container, and by that bypassing the described problem, e.g:
http://cubiq.org/iscroll-5